# Cannot add DockPanel into VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

i am having a bit of a problem with a dockpanel, that being I cannot get it to work.

I have installed the toolkit for silverlight 4, as shown in this link:

http://procbits.com/2011/07/19/missing-dockpanel-add-dockpanel-for-silverlight-4-or-silverlight-5

but i have no suck luck in getting it to work, it says : "the type 'tk:Dockpanel' was not found'

Any help on this would be great

Comment: I see you have the windows phone tag, did you install the Siverlight for windows phone toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

Add this dll manually to the references,

```
System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit
```

also, define the namespace like this

```
  xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
```

If its a windows phone you need to install the version of silverlight supporting windows phone.